# AspNet core MVC 1.1.3 Default selected radio button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to default a radio button to be checked.

```
<div>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, "OofDeactive", new { @class = "isActive", @checked="checked"})</div>
<div>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, "OofActive", new { @class = "isActive" })</div>
```

Note that the model contains a property

```
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

I have found the same issue here but for MVC6 although it is closed: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3098

Is this an issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your code seems correct only. First one should be checked by default.

Comment: Bro, i think your IsActive is false. That's why it's not selecting. Check once what is the value.

Comment: @BasantaMatia I have server debugged it to ensure that the isActive is coming in correctly. Eventually I would have it so that @@checked = model.isactive to default it to checked when isactive is true. But I cant even get it to default manually.

Comment: What is property `IsActive`? It sounds like a `bool`. Its the value of the property which determines what is selected. Unless `IsActive` is a `string` and its value when you pass the model to the view is `"OofDeactive"` then the first button will not be selected.

Comment: @StephenMuecke IsActive is a bool passed from the controller. I have set the value of the radiobutton to the string "OofDeactive" for other javascript functionality. I have tested whether this value field determines the default checked property and it doesn't.

Comment: You cannot do that - a `bool` only binds to `true` or `false` (and that is what the `value` attributes of your radio buttons need to be). And what other functionality - your going about this the wrong way.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I have changed it to this, when I look at source, the value of the input tag is set to true and false as expected but checked html attribute is on the false value input. Does this not mean the value field on the helper tag is not connected to the checked html property?


<code><div>\@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, Model.IsActive, new { \@id = "active" }) Send automatic replies</div>
    <div>\@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, !Model.IsActive, new { \@id = "deactive" }) Do not send automatic replies</div></code>

Comment: It needs to be `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, true, new { id = "active" })` and `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, false, new { id = "deactive" })` and if the value of `IsActive` is `true`, the first radio button will be selected, otherwise the 2nd will be (model binding works by binding to the value of your property)

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's the one. I need to read more! Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RadioButtonFor()` (as do all the `HtmlHelper` methods) work by binding to the value of your property and its that value which determines which radio button is checked.

Your `IsActive` property is a `bool` which has only 2 possible values, `true` and `false` and cannot bind to `string` with values of "OofDeactive" or "OofActive". Change the code to

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, true, new { @class = "isActive", id = "" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, false, new { @class = "isActive", id = "" })
```

And if the value of property `IsActive` is `true` the first radio button will be selected, otherwise the 2nd will be.

Note that the `RadioButtonFor()` method generates duplicate `id` attributes so either use `new { id = "" }` to remove the `id` attribute (or give them a unique `id` if needed for some other purpose). Setting the `checked` attribute is pointless since it will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
 @{
    var checked = Model.IsActive ? new {@checked = "checked"} : null;
var checked1 = checked == null ? new {@checked = "checked"} : null;
    }

          <div>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, "OofDeactive", checked)</div>
            <div>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, "OofActive", checked1)</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, neither of the radio buttons are selected. I have checked the source and the input tag does not have the checked html attribute.

Comment: can you try this `<div>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsActive, "OofDeactive", isChecked: true, new { @class = "isActive"})</div>`

Comment: I am getting a error as there are not overloads for methods RadioButtonFor that takes 4 arguments.

Comment: You want if isActive is true then it should be checked when is active is false it should not be checked correct ?

Comment: Yes, well, if it's true, one is checked if false then the other is.

Comment: I have updated my answer can you try that. I have create a code block to check isactive and use it

Comment: This has resulted in both radio buttons being unchecked.

Comment: I have updated my answer I have added another variable to see if checked is null or not